# (Theoretical) Multivariable Calculus Textbooks

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation, big-list

(Note that I have used bold text frequently simply to highlight the key points of my question for those who do not have the time to read through it thoroughly (it is not very long, however); I hope this is not considered offensive.)

There are many textbooks on multivariable calculus. However, some textbooks on multivariable calculus do not focus very much on the **theoretical foundations** of the subject. For example, a textbook might state a result along the lines of "the order of partial differentiation is immaterial" without proof and ask the student to use this rule to solve problems. Similarly, theorems such as those due to Green and Stokes are often not proved in their full generality.

Therefore, I ask the following question:

> What are some good **theoretical
>   multivariable calculus textbooks**?

Since "theoretical" is somewhat ambiguous, let me state the following criteria which I would like a "theoretical" textbook on multivariable calculus to satisfy:

- The textbook should be **rigorous** and it should **not state a theorem without proof** if the theorem is proved in at least one other multivariable calculus textbook. (Of course, the textbook may *omit* certain theorems; however, this criterion at least ensures that major theorems in multivariable calculus are not stated without proof and used purely for the sake of computations. Also, this criterion permits the textbook to state an interesting theorem if it is beyond the scope of all multivariable calculus textbooks.)
- The textbook should be *primarily* based on developing the theoretical foundations of multivariable calculus; therefore, applications such as learning how to compute the partial derivative of a function, learning how to solve extremum problems, learning how to compute etc. **should be kept to a minimum**. In particular, the textbook can *assume* that the reader has already seen at least an informal treatment of the subject where these aspects are emphasized.
- The textbook should have a rigorous treatment of **differentiability in $n$-dimensional Euclidean space** (e.g., the inverse and implicit function theorems should be proven), **Riemann integration in $n$-space**, and **differential forms** (e.g., Stokes theorem should be proven). It would also be a bonus if the book treated the general concept of a manifold.
- **Textbooks with minimal prerequisites are preferred**; however, please feel free to suggest books meeting the above criteria even if the prerequisites are quite demanding.
- Finally, it would also be preferable, but not essential, for the book to **only treat multivariable calculus**.

Examples of books meeting the above criteria: "Analysis on Manifolds" by James Munkres, "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" by Walter Rudin, and "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak.

Although I have studied theoretical multivariable calculus already (four years ago), I could never find "the perfect book" (relative to myself, of course). Every book has its virtues; Rudin for its elegance, Munkres for its beautiful exposition, and Spivak for its "quick and dirty" approach. I am hoping that someone will be able to suggest a book that (relative to myself) is "perfect". Also, this question can be useful to other students who have not yet studied the subject and wish to learn it.

Thank you very much for all answers! **Please do feel free to suggest as many books as you can think of** so we can form a big list. Also, please try to **explain why a particular book is good** or at least why *you think* it is good. I suppose it is fine to suggest a book that is already suggested provided you have a different view as to why the book is good.

Comment: In order to encourage further recommendations of textbooks in multivariable calculus meeting the criteria above, I have added a bounty of 50 reputation. (The recommendations thus far are fantastic and I thank the answerers; however, I would like to encourage further people to add their recommendations to this list.)

Comment: @Javier: it's nice that you're so enthousiastic, but given that this question is very personal and subjective, your wording seems a bit stong. I don't understand claims like 'by far the best books are..' or 'by no means I would use any other titles', unless you have read every single existing book on earth about the subject. And  'no one will ever need any other book on the topic' almost sounds arrogant.

Comment: @Javier: I understand that your answers are (meant to be read as) subjective. By the way, I also appreciate your passionatic book recommendations as seen in in other MS questions. Rather than cultural or educational, it is probably a personal thing: I tend to be overly modest and careful about what words to use. I don't like the wording 'no one will ever need...' because it suggests that anyone who thinks he does need another book, has not 'seen the light' or must be at a lower level or something like that. Anyway, let's keep at that, everone has his own styling of expressing himself.

Comment: By the way, have you read/seen Dieudonné's Treatise on Analysis? While it is of course a series of books, as a whole it is mindblowingly comprehensive (as I just found out), and I think his style is very clear. I also like the combination of Lang's Undergraduate Analysis+Functional Analysis. I am not familiar with Zorich, by the way.

Comment: I see there was another reply after 'finally'. As I am being arrogant and troublesome, you might want to ignore my last question and reply to save the trouble.

Comment: @wildildildlife: Dieudonné's books were very used and recommened in Spain where I did undergraduate. They are a classic masterpiece although a bit dated, that is why new books like Zorich are very welcomed. I used Lang's Undergraduate Analysis but found it incomplete and too "narrative" as well, but Lang's "Real Analysis" is a great complement to Zorich' since fills the gap of Banach, Hilbert spaces, measure theory, operators, etc... Most people are not familiar with Zorich, above all outside Europe that is why I recommend it so strongly to help make it more known.

Comment: @Javier: Well, as it happens the analysis course at the university where I am following two (other) courses at the moment, are using Zorich. This is in Europe, btw. While we're at it, the two books Basic/Advanced Real Analysis by Knapp are one of my favourites (I am fond of Knapp's writing style). Although I have the feeling that with Dieudonné and Knapp we're drifting away from multivariable calculus, and towards more advanced analysis.

Comment: Dieudonné and Knapp are for me on the threshold to real analysis beyond calculus, that is why I beleive Zorich is perfect since it develops carefully and rigorously from one variable calculus up to differential forms and Stokes theorem without entering too much the realm of analysis on manifolds which is beyond calculus. For that, the books by Duistermaat you mention are wonderful but they are too advanced to be self-contained while Zorich even proofs every differentiation and integration rule and method but reaches up to constant rank, implicit function theorems and the like.

Comment: @wildildildlife: I don't think there was anything offensive or arrogant in Javier's posts, it's just sheer enthusiasm. I always like to hear strong and passionate opinions about something I am evaluating or don't have an opinion of yet. And even if I do, and it's different from someone elses, it's still nice to hear a different view. You shouldn't think of it as offensive, it's not meant as "telling you what to do and think", it's just happiness that such a good book exists and an opinion that it's overlooked. **Good math books are extremely rare** in my experience...

Comment: I am happy if people express their views on the textbooks recommended here; after all, this is what I am looking for in asking this question. I think that these days people tend to be afraid to be too passionate and this (fear) is not a good thing. On the other hand, everyone has differing opinions on mathematics textbooks, and while I thank Leon for his reference and agree that it is a very good one, I would not go as far as saying that "no-one will ever need another book on the topic". But that does not mean I am against someone saying that; if that is how you feel about the book, go ahead!

Comment: @Leon Although this is slightly off-topic, I do have to disagree that "good math books are extremely rare" for two main reasons. The first is that sometimes one may simply be searching in the wrong place for a math book on a topic and come to the conclusion that there is no good math book on the topic. I know I have; e.g., I tend to be biased and look at Graduate Texts in Mathematics, Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics, American Mathematical Society books when I search. Secondly, often what constitutes a "good" mathematics book varies greatly from individual to individual.

Comment: Methods of Nonlinear Analysis: Applications to Differential Equations by Drabek and Milota, Advanced Calculus by Hans Sagan, also the text by Apostol on Mathematical Analysis and as has been mentioned Zorich is amazing and beastly. Great question even if it has been asked before.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

A book fitting your description quite well is

[Multidimensional Real Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521551145) by Duistermaat and Kolk, a 2-volume set: Differentiation and Integration.

It has rigorous, slick proofs, is highly theoretical, but with lots of (advanced) examples and many, many exercises. Much attention is given to the Inverse and Implicit Function theorem, and submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$. The book is used in a second-year course at Utrecht University. I have to admit that it was quite hard to read for me when I took the course. But it is great as a reference, and years later I still consult it now and then.

Another nice book is Loomis & Sternberg - [Advanced Calculus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0867201223) (freely available from [Sternberg's website](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~shlomo/).)

Comment: @wildildildlife This is an excellent recommendation! I had never heard about this book before but it does indeed look like a book satisfying my criteria. Thank you very much!

Comment: @wildildildlife I really do have to emphasize that this must be one of the best multivariable calculus textbooks that I have seen. I am really pleased that you mentioned this book! I do have to read it in more detail but the choice of topics (in the table of contents) is exactly what a mathematics student needs plus a lot more.

Comment: @wildildildlife Judging from its TOC, The Duistermaat and Kolk book looks really good. Nice reccomendation!

Comment: This book is lying on my desk now. I took the course of Kolk using this book a couple of years ago. Back then I was still a physics student, and this might have pulled me over. It is indeed wonderful.

Comment: I have accepted this answer but the bounty of $50$ reputation is still open. I will award the bounty by tomorrow and any further answers to this question are welcome; it is still possible to win this bounty even if you have not answered the question yet.

Comment: Dear wildildildlife, your recommendation is one of the best textbooks in multivariable calculus that I have seen. It is comprehensive, rigorous, and filled with exercises that introduce the reader to a number of important concepts in analysis. I really was amazed by this textbook. I am awarding the 50 reputation to you for these reasons and more. Thank you very much for suggesting this textbook!

Comment: @Amitesh: You're welcome, and thanks for the bounty. It is indeed an amazing book :) Kolk en the late Duistermaat have done a remarkable job. [You might want to take a look at their other books on Lie groups and Distribution theory.]

Comment: @wildildildlife Thanks for telling me about these books on Lie groups and distribution theory! I will have a look at them.

Comment: @wildildildlife This book is brilliant !

Answer (score 24):

This is a lazy answer from a guy, who in his first and second year felt the need for an excellent exact rigorous and intuitive book in calculus, both one and several variables.

I haven't read any of the following books, but I have browsed through them.

- *[Mathematical Analysis I](http://www.springer.com/br/book/9783540874515)*, Zorich, [amazon](http://www.springer.com/br/book/9783540874539), 578 pages
- *[Mathematical Analysis II](http://library.nu/docs/OGIAJ8LQ0R/Mathematical%20Analysis%20II%20%28Universitext%29)*, Zorich, [amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540874534), 688 pages
- *[Advanced Calculus](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441973311)*, Callahan

I was impressed to no end by his table of contents:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I was going to answer exactly those books!! I AGREE COMPLETELY. These titles are so amazingly good and complete, no one will ever need any other book on the topic. Callahan in particular is extremely well-done, filled with figures and graphics and geometric motivations. Zorich is more complete as it deals with one variable and some general Banach analysis and other more specialized topics. THEY ARE THE ULTIMATE REFERENCE FOR RIGOROUS THEORETICAL ADVANCED CALCULUS.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much! This looks like a very good reference.

Comment: I may have just seen the face of God in those tables of contents. +1.

Comment: +1. I REALLY don't think any of us can improve on these recommendations.There are a few books just as good,but certainly not BETTER then these.

Comment: please delete the expletive

Answer (score 9):

There is a recent book [Functions of Several Real Variables](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9814299278). It has lot of good examples and exercises and is certainly theoretical.

Comment: Thanks Vishal! It's been a while since I asked this question (2 years!) but it's great to accumulate so many good references. I think this book is one of the best out of all those suggested by the answers!

Comment: It is a lovely book indeed. I hope more and more users discover this book and benefit by it.

Comment: @AmiteshDatta  , then you should accept this answer instead of the other one.

Answer (score 7):

The second half of the book "An Introduction to Analysis" by William Wade supplies what you ask. (The first half is single variable.)  There is even a section on elementary Fourier analysis.

Table of Contents (for multivariable part):

**8 Euclidean Spaces**

8.1: Algebraic Structure

8.2: Planes and Linear Transformations

8.3: Topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$

8.4: Interior, closure, and boundary

**9 Convergence in $\mathbb{R}^n$**

9.1: Limits of sequences

9.2: Limits of functions

9.3: Continuous functions

9.4: Compact sets

9.5: Applications

**10 Metric Spaces**

10.1: Introduction

10.2: Limits of functions

10.3: Interior, closure, boundary

10.4: Compact sets

10.5: Connected sets

10.6: Continuous functions

**11 Differentiability in $\mathbb{R}^n$**

11.1: Partial derivatives and partial integrals

11.2: Definition of differentiability

11.3: Derivatives, differentials, and tangent planes

11.4: Chain rule

11.5: Mean Value Theorem and Taylor's Formula

11.6: Inverse Function Theorem

11.7: Optimization (Lagrange Multipliers)

**12 Integration on $\mathbb{R}^n$**

12.1: Jordan regions

12.2: Riemann integration on Jordan regions

12.3: Iterated integrals

12.4: Change of variables

12.5: Partitions of unity

12.6: Gamma function and volume

**13 Fundamental Theorem of Vector Calculus**

13.1: Curves

13.2: Oriented curves

13.3: Surfaces

13.4: Oriented surfaces

13.5: Theorems of Green and Gauss

13.6: Stokes's Theorem

**14 Fourier Series**

14.1: Introduction

14.2: Summability of Fourier series

14.3: Growth of Fourier coefficients

14.4: Convergence of Fourier series

14.5: Uniqueness

**15 Differentiable Manifolds**

15.1: Differential forms on $\mathbb{R}^n$

15.2: Differentiable manifolds

15.3: Stokes's Theorem on manifolds

Comment: +1 Thank you very much! Could you please give a link to an online version of this book if possible? I cannot seem to view the book online. (The table of contents would also be useful.)

Comment: Got the title wrong.  Corrected that.

Comment: There is no online version.

Comment: @Shahab  SHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH! THAT SITE DOES NOT EXIST! You want them to shut it down for copyright breach?!?LOL

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 The site was shut down at some point in the past week ...

Comment: @Amitesh Don't remind me. The corporate police state is encroaching further and further on the ability of poor students to have access to materials they can't afford.

Comment: I personally don't like Wade... messy arrangement, ugly proofs, lack of important material, and bad writing...

Answer (score 3):

I've been reading Mathematical Analysis by Tom Apostol to review much of this material. He seems to discuss and explain things more than Rudin. He even includes a few pictures, which are understandably primitive given the age of the book but I think they help. He also seems to have a lot of exercises.

Comment: I will add that the notation for Derivatives used in this book has fallen out of favor, though I am using a first edition, does anyone know if the second edition is updated in this respect?

Comment: In the 2nd edition, at page 347, he write $\mathbf{T_c}:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ for the total derivative at $\mathbf{c}$ of $f:S\subset\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$. It's probably better to somehow use $f$ in the notation, like $\mathbf{T_c}f$. This would agree with what some people use for the 'tangent mapping' of a function between manifolds. But he does use $\mathbf{Df(c)}$ for the Jacobian matrix.

Comment: If you can get an old hard copy that still has the library smell. Oh man, that is living. Also, in a similar vein, get a copy of Hans Sagan's advanced calculus text. These are both formidable texts from a simpler time with better students (in US schools anyway)