# A book like Michael Spivaks Calculus, for multivariate Calculus.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, soft-question, book-recommendation

Is there a book like Michael Spivaks Calculus, that is for Multivariate Calculus? That is a "real analysis" multivariate calculus book?

Comment: Like his "Calculus on Manifolds"?  Pretty sure that's like his "Calculus". ;)

Comment: @Hayden Thanks, I'll try to check that one out.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/44527).

Comment: @GitGud I'll check that one out aswell, thanks.