# Seeking Recommendation on Theoretical Multivariable Calculus textbooks

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation

I am a college sophomore with double majors in mathematics and microbiology. I wrote this email to seek your advice on selecting a theoretical, proof-based textbook on the multivariable calculus. I will be taking a multivariable calculus on this Summer but it unfortunately is a computational one with little theories. I would like one that comprehensively covers the theories of multivariable calculus and perhaps including sections on the applications too (but not necessary). Couple of textbooks I have in my mind are ones written by Serge Lang, Apostol, Marsden, Hubbard, and Fleming. Which one is good for self-learning?

Sincerely,

PK

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44522/theoretical-multivariable-calculus-textbooks?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can't go wrong with baby Rudin:
http://smile.amazon.com/Principles-Mathematical-Analysis-Rudin/dp/1259064786/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1428694274&sr=8-1&keywords=rudin