# Book reference for Double/ triple integrals

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

Can someone please suggest me a Calculus book that includes Double integrals, triple integrals, volume bounded between two curves, line integrals and surface inetgrals?

I am looking for a book with plenty of examples and with geometrical approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of books that include the topics you are interested. Here are few suggestions you could look into:

Advanced Calculus: A Geometric View, James J. Callahan

Vector Calculus, Peter Baxandall and Hans Liebeck

And for friendly introduction online see:
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/CalcIII.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I personally liked Susan Colley's *Vector Calculus, Fourth Edition*. It can be terse in some places, and its approach is not entirely geometric, but I still think it is a decent book. It's the book that I learned multivariable calculus from and have used it for several semesters to tutor that course.

Answer (score 1):

Other than J. Callahan's book (as suggest by @Harto Saarinen)which is a great book, there are two books that i find it "complete" and those are focusing on both theoretical aspect and practical purpose. **V. Zorich** - ["Mathematical Analysis Vol. I and II"](http://www.springer.com/br/book/9783540874515) and **Moskowitz and Paliogiannis** - [Function of Several Variables](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9814299278). There are tons of other possible choices, you can look at them here [(Theoretical) Multivariable Calculus Textbooks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44522/theoretical-multivariable-calculus-textbooks).