# Book on Multiple Riemann Integrals

Tags: book-recommendation

As an assignment my professor recommended looking for information about multiple Riemann integration. That is, as in the $\mathbb{R}$ case, using partitions on an interval (in this case it would have to be an $n-$dimensional interval), Riemann sums over those partitions, upper and lower sums, Jordan content as a multiple Riemann integral, and the middle value theorem for these multiple Riemann integrals. However, I've reviewed every book in my library and none of them have this information on it. I can search each of this topics by its own but at the moment I haven't had great success and a book with all these topics included would be nice to read.

That's why I'm interested in books or articles treating most (if not all are possible) of the mentioned topics.

Comment: Calculus on Manifolds by Spivak and Analysis on Manifolds by Munkres cover this well.  Other standard real analysis books like Apostol, Bartle, etc.  have some material but are not as thorough.

Comment: You will find some good suggestions here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43290/references-for-multivariable-calculus, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44522/theoretical-multivariable-calculus-textbooks.