# What is a good study guide for several variables analysis?

Tags: real-analysis

I’m a senior student in math. I want to study several variables analysis. Two years ago, I studied *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* up to chapter 8.

To study several variables analysis, should I read Rudin, chapters 9 – 11; Spivak’s *Calculus on Manifolds*; or another book? What is the best choice?

Answer (score 1):

I think Spivak's "Calculus on Manifolds" is much more student-friendly than Rudin's PMA.  (I also really dislike Chapter 10 of Rudin, which is a rather odd treatment of differential forms.)  Chapter 11 of Rudin, by the way, is not about analysis of several variables, but rather about measure theory.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43290/references-for-the-multivariate-calculus) might contain some other references which you might consider.