# How does the $D^ku(x)\in \mathbb R^{n^k}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, reference-request

I got the definition from the book :-Partial differential equations,American Mathematical Society,Lawrence C Evans.

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be an open subset. An expression of the form
$$F(D^ku(x),D^{k-1}u(x),..., Du(x),u(x),x)=0(x\in U)$$
is called a k-th order partial differential equation, where
$$F:\mathbb R^{n^k}\times \mathbb R^{n^{k-1}}\times...\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R\times U\to \mathbb R$$ is given, and
$$u:U\to \mathbb R$$ is the unknown function.

Doubt on the definition.
I know, $x\in U\subseteq \mathbb R^n$

$u(x)\in R$

$Du(x)\in R^n$ ($\because$ it is a gradient.)

..........

How does the $D^ku(x)\in \mathbb R^{n^k}$?
Could you suggest some readings for more clarity?

Comment: This is explained in Appendix A, p. 701. Unfortunately it is not quite correct: $D^k u(x)$ is not the **set** of all partial derivatives of order $k$, but the **indexed family** $(D^\alpha u(x))_{\lvert \alpha \rvert = k}$. This can be identified with an element of $\mathbb R^{n^k}$ since there are $n^k$ multiindices $\alpha$ of order $k$.

Comment: Why $|\alpha|?$

Comment: This is defined on p. 701. We have $\alpha = (\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ where the $\alpha_i$ are integers $\ge 0$ and $\lvert \alpha \rvert = \alpha_1+\ldots +\alpha_n$. The indexed family for order $k$ consists of all $D^\alpha u(x)$ with $\lvert \alpha \rvert = k$.

Comment: Only 664 pages  in this text.

Comment: I used the second edition which has 749 pages. http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~xushijie/pdf/textbooks/pde-evans.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly: as you know, $Du(x) \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I.e., you can express the differential of a function $u$ as a linear combination of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}, \dots, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}$.

For $D^2u(x)$, you need to consider all the combinations $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$. This is $n^2$. For any $k$, how many combinations of $\frac{\partial^k}{\partial x_{i_1}\dots \partial x_{i_k}}$ do you have? This is $n^k$.

I suggest you to double-check multivariate calculus. Take a look to this post, where there are many good references suggested: [References for multivariable calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43290/references-for-multivariable-calculus)